# Getting a list of applications with SMS permission

Tags: sms, permissions, battery-life

I installed many applications, and some of them have specific permissions. How do I get a list of all applications with a specific permission? I'm interested in SMS permissions. I do not want to write an app for that yet :-)

My problem is that the Galaxy Nexus 4.2.1 Messaging app takes up too much CPU - over 20%. So, I need to see which of my installed apps may be misbehaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a FREE app called [Permission Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carlocriniti.android.permission_explorer&hl=en). Check the MESSAGES category in that app.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Trust Go Antivirus & Mobile Security](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trustgo.mobile.security). Protects your phone while providing many benefits. One been being able to know what app use what permissions.